# How can I print contents of a text file in git bash?

Tags: git-bash

How can I print contents of a text file  in git bash?

I added to the text file through git bash using echo "Hello World!" > my_text.txt
now I just want to be able to view only in git bash.

Comment: cat will dump the file to the console as @Glech pointed out. To edit the file you can use `vi <your file>`, but the editor is not very user friendly, you will be better editting it in Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cat <your file>` for example